# Java Jframe Source Code string

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I'm programming a `Jframe` `TicTacToe` game and want that the program draws an `O` when the int is equal and a X when the int is unequal.
I got this source code:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
   if (i%2==0)
   String Y = "X"; {
     else {
       String Z = "O";
     } // end of if-else
   } // end of if
```

and got 3 error messages:

```
TicTacToe.java:156:8: error: not a statement
   String Y = "X"; {
   ^
TicTacToe.java:156:14: error: ';' expected
   String Y = "X"; {
         ^
TicTacToe.java:157:10: error: 'else' without 'if'
     else {
     ^
3 errors
```

I would appreciate every help :)
Sorry for my bad english (not native)

Answer (score 0):

One of the errors is because you misplaced the curly braces should be:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
   if (i%2==0){
      String Y = "X"; 
   }else {
      String Z = "O";
   } // end of if-else
}
```

or remove the braces all together:

```
public void jButton1_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) { 
   if (i%2==0)
       String Y = "X"; 
   else 
       String Z = "O";
}
```

Comment: Thank you this problem is solved... 
Problem left now is the if else :D

Comment: What's the new exception that you are getting? I mean what's the compiler complaining this time about?